# DataFrame Pandas - How can I split a list of dictionary from each row to separated columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the DataFrame below with 2 columns, and one of the columns is a list of dictionary inside an list of dictionary.
I would like to split/separate this column in several columns.

```
import pandas as pd

USERNAME = ['root', 'user1', 'user2','user3']
test_data = '[{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actualOperator":"contains","_actualValue":"LBD","attr":"displayName","op":"contains","value":"LBD"}],"name":"test_Event","editable":true}]'
test_data2 = '[{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actualOperator":"not_contains","_actualValue":"AAA","attr":"Event","op":"contains","value":"LBD"}],"name":"test_Event","editable":true}]'
test_data3 = '[{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actualOperator":"exclude","_actualValue":"BBB","attr":"Event","op":"contains","value":"LBD"}],"name":"test_Event","editable":true}]'
test_data4 = '[{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actualOperator":"adding","_actualValue":"CASA","attr":"displayName","op":"contains","value":"LBD"}],"name":"test_Event","editable":true}]'
VALUE_STRING = [test_data, test_data2, test_data3, test_data4]

data = {'USERNAME': ['root', 'user1', 'user2','user3'], 'VALUE_STRING' : VALUE_STRING}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

USERNAME    VALUE_STRING
root        [{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actual...
user1       [{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actual...
user2       [{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actual...
user2       [{"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"_actual...
```

And I expected a result like this:

```
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({'USERNAME': ['root', 'user1', 'user2','user3'], 
                            '_actualOperator':['contains','not_contains','exclude','adding'],
                           '_actualValue':['LBD','AAA','BBB','CASA'],
                           'attr':['displayName','Event','Event','displayName']})
df_expected

USERNAME    _actualOperator     _actualValue    attr
root        contains            LBD             displayName
user1       not_contains        AAA             Event
user2       exclude             BBB             Event
user3       adding              CASA            displayName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the column `VALUE_STRING` contains json data, in that case we can parse the json data using `loads` method of `json` module, then extract the dictionaries associated with the key `expressions` from each row, create a new dataframe from these dictionaries and join back with `USERNAME` column

```
import json

s = df['VALUE_STRING'].map(json.loads)\
     .str[0].str['expressions'].str[0]

exp = pd.DataFrame([*s], index=s.index)
df_out = df[['USERNAME']].join(exp).drop(['op', 'value'], axis=1)
```

Alternative approach with pandas `json_normalize` method

```
s = df['VALUE_STRING'].map(json.loads).str[0]
exp = pd.json_normalize(s, 'expressions')
df_out = df[['USERNAME']].join(exp).drop(['op', 'value'], axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df_out)

  USERNAME _actualOperator _actualValue         attr
0     root        contains          LBD  displayName
1    user1    not_contains          AAA        Event
2    user2         exclude          BBB        Event
3    user3          adding         CASA  displayName
```